# Serverless Framework / Python - Deploying multiple functions in a service

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm using the *Serverless framework* with *AWS Lambda* to deploy multiple functions, one of them is written in *Python3* and bundled with a few external libraries I'm using (redis, elasticsearch, dateutil).
When running the lambda locally using `serverless invoke local --function function-name` it works fine. When running locally using `python3 function.py` I'm getting the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, because I am importing a local python file using a dot prefix i.e `from .imported_file import one, two, three`. When running on cloud i.e `serverless invoke --function function-name`, I'm getting the error `Unable to import module 'function-name/function': No module named 'redis'`.

Since I'm deploying multiple functions under the same yaml file, each function has it's own folder, and I'm deploying using the following settings:

```yaml
package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - "*/**"
    - "*"
```

And in each function:

```yaml
package:
      include:
        - function-name/**
```

File structure looks like this:

```
service-name/
├─ function-name/
│  ├─ packages/
│  │  ├─ dateutil/
│  │  ├─ elasticsearch/
│  │  ├─ redis/
│  ├─ function.py
│  ├─ imported_file.py
├─ function-name-2/
├─ serverless.yaml
```

I've tried lots of things to overcome this, but mainly what seems to be working is having all the files and folders in the root folder of the lambda. Problem is I'm unable to accomplish this because using the method above to package the functions forces a file structure looking like this:

```
./
├─ function-name/
│  ├─ packages/
│  ├─ function.py
```

Instead of this:

```
./
├─ packages/
├─ function.py
```

If someones can explain to me what's going on and how to get it working in the cloud, it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by setting `PYTHONPATH` as environment variable pointing to the local `packages/` folder.